# error writing session to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, storage, passport.js, middleware

I'm working on a node app and using MongoDB to store session. The app uses Linkedin oAuth and MongoDB.

**My code:**

```
var store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: mongoUri,
    collection: '_sessions',
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

// Catch MONGO CONNECTION errors
store.on('error', function(error) {
    assert.ifError(error);
    assert.ok(false);
});

// if (isLocal) {
//     app.use(session({resave: 'true', saveUninitialized: 'true', secret: 'keyboardcat'}));
// }else{
// }
app.use(session({
    store: store,
    resave: 'true',
    saveUninitialized: 'true',
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}));
```

**I get the following error when the app launches.**

```
Error: Error setting ZwkuhpnbkYgD1HzscBJ8w2fmhwZpiQPL to Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2016-09-20T22:20:15.753Z,
     originalMaxAge: 604800000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: null,
     domain: null },
  passport: {},
  'oauth2:www.linkedin.com': { state: 'DqyHf7eqG8RCN7BYRkG9NSUV' } }: The dotted field 'oauth2:www.linkedin.com' in 'session.oauth2:www.linkedin.com' is not valid for storage.
    at /Users/vc/Sites/HavasCognitiveID/node_modules/connect-mongodb-session/index.js:147:19
    at handleCallback (/Users/vc/Sites/HavasCognitiveID/node_modules/connect-mongodb-session/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /Users/vc/Sites/HavasCognitiveID/node_modules/connect-mongodb-session/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1008:42
    at handler (/Users/vc/Sites/HavasCognitiveID/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:414:5)[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

I understand that mongodb complains about the dotted field. My question is how do I intercept the session after the user is authenticated before it's written to the passport:{}?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the 'sessionKey' that is used by adding it as an option when defining the LinkedIn strategy

passport.use(new LinkedinStrategy({ ...options, sessionKey: 'linkedin'}, strategies.linkedin));